# Get the first letter of a word and bring it to the end

Tags: java, for-loop, substring, charat

How can I get the first letter of a word and bring it to the end?

Comment: please look at your post, notice things went wrong, and then format it properly.

Comment: Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the `i`th letter each time, when you should take the first letter with index `0` each time.  Change

```
firstLetter = word.charAt(i);
```

to

```
firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Im just making sure , so the word+=firstletter make the word go to the secondletter in the word right.

Comment: Not quite.  Doing `word = word.substring(1, word.length());` effectively takes off the first letter of the word, which you have already determined in the line before, with `firstLetter = word.charAt(i);`.  Then `word += firstLetter;` effectively appends the first letter to the end of the word.  All together, those 3 lines create the "wrap around" shifting effect that was your aim.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
word = "test";
newWord = word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
        word = word.substring(1, word.length());
        System.out.println(firstLetter + word);

        word += firstLetter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A sightly different approach: leave the word as is, and iterate through the permutations based on substrings. After all: "omputerc" is just [omputer] + [c], which is [c][omputer] swapped; the next iteration is "mputerco" which is just [mputer] + [co], or [co][mputer] swapped, and so forth:

```
String head, tail;
for (int i = 0, last = word.length()-1; i<last; i++) {
  head = word.substring(0,i);
  tail = word.substring(i,last);
  System.out.println(tail + head);
}
```

We leave the word as is, grab the head and tail substrings, and print them in reverse order, producing exactly what you need.